# Regex to parse characters within <>

Tags: regex

I want to remove all characters that appear between `<>` unless it starts with `<&`.

This is due to an internal system that requires some macro tags but needs to strip all HTML from the string.

I have it partially working but it is also removing the detail between the tag, for example it will also remove the 'word' from within:

```
<span>word</span>
```

My regex is:

```
(<[^&]*>)|(&nbsp;)
```

And can be found with example text:

http://regexr.com/39hfj

Comment: Yes. what programming language do you use? and just show full fragment of your script running the regex you show us

Comment: Have you tried `(<[^&>]*>)|(&nbsp;)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<[^&]*>` matches any string between `<>` as long as it doesn't have `&`. You want to match any string that doesn't have `&` and `>` in it. Use `<[^&>]*>` for that. (another way is to use lazy flag as mentioned in the other answer).

By the way, what is the expected behaviour for this input string?

```
some text <a title="a & b">hello</a>
```

Your current regex will not match the opening anchor tag in this string as it contains `&`. But I believe you care about `&` only when it immediately follows `<`, right?

In that case, you just need to make sure that first character is not `&`

```
(<[^&].*?>)
```

But this will not match empty tags; if you care about empty tags, add them with a `|`

```
(<[^&].*?>|<>)
```

Comment: Yes your correct on the last part it needs to only ignore <& not something that contains & later on in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `?` after the asterisk to be non-greedy and to stop at the first occurance of `>`: `(<[^&]*?>)|(&nbsp;)`